# NotesJSONNavigator and Appendelement weird result when adding currency

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a very simple code and weird result (from my point of view).

```
Dim s As New notessession
Dim jsonNav As NotesJSONNavigator
Dim c As Currency

Set jsonNav = s.Createjsonnavigator("")
Call jsonNav.Appendelement(4, "literal")

c = 4
Call jsonNav.Appendelement(c, "variable")

MsgBox jsonNav.Stringify()
```

The result looks wrong (unless HCL does it for a purpose)

> {"literal":4,"variable":40000}

Does anybody know if it is possible to add variable with type 'Currency' to JSON using 'native' methods and get it as it is in JSON?

Things works well if I switch to type: 'Double' so I wonder why it works like that.

Thanks.

**update**

I have just noticed that HCL documentation does not include Currency.
Allowed types are String , Integer, Long, Double, Boolean.
So maybe it's according to design:
https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_APPENDELEMENT_METHOD_NJN.html
I have changed solution to use Double instead of Currency and all is working well now.

Comment: Looks like a Notes bug to me.